# Specific number of values in field setting per role

Tags: entities, users

Is there any way to limit user input a field with 1 value in select list, but make it unlimited for admin?

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  You can manipulate the `multiple` characteristic of the `select` via a `form_alter()` hook.  You just have to make sure the field itself is a multiple value field to start with, and then do something along these lines:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  if ( /* your user is NOT an admin */ ) {

    if ($form_id == 'YOURNODETYPE_node_form') {

      $form['#field_info']['field_NAMEOFTHEFIELD']['multiple']=FALSE;

    }

  }

  // any other form alters here

}
```

If this doesn't work out of the box for you, a `drupal_set_message()` and `print_r()` of your `$form` will give you a dump of what you have to work with, and you basically just want to find the `multiple` array key for the field in question and change it to `FALSE` for non admins.

But once again, you need to make this field a multiple value field to begin with, but you then don't allow non-admins to enter multiple values into it on the form.

(More information on the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#multiple) can be found [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#multiple) for D7 if this doesn't work as the above is just a quick edit on a D6 testbed here)

Comment: In case I want to set 1 value first and then check multiple for admin so can I do like this:

$form['#field_info']['field_NAMEOFTHEFIELD']['multiple']=true;

Comment: a multiple value field does not make you have to select multiple values, it only allows you the option to do so if you want.  it will already be set to TRUE since the field ***has*** to be a multiple value field to start off with because of the DB design of Drupal, so you need to turn off the ability of non admins to enter more than one value into it.  you can't do it the other way around, eg, create a single value field and then alter it to take multiple values in the form.