# Multiple field value amount based on role

Tags: users, entities

I am looking to add a single image field to a content type, and allow a different amount of images based on a users role.

- Business Free User can upload 1 image (as profile pic)
- Business Silver User can upload 3 images
- Business Gold Users can upload 9 images

I've been searching high and low for a module to swoop in and save the day, but im not having much luck. Has anyone found something that can do this for me?

I'm using the field permissions modules to hide fields based on role. The fall back here would be to have 3 images fields, one for logo, one for 2 more images (to make 3) and one for 6 more images (to make 9) but I'm building a pretty big site here and would like to reduce the amount of fields where I can.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this question: [Specific number of values in field setting per role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/specific-number-of-values-in-field-setting-per-role). The hook_form_alter method is the way I would approach it.